# Popen printing weird whitespace

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess, popen

I am trying to run ssh using subprocess.Popen. It works, but keeps printing some weird whitespace. As the time goes on, whitespace increases

```
Hi
Hi
Hi
Hi
Hi
Hi
Hi
  Hi
    Hi
      Hi
        Hi
          Hi
            Hi
              Hi
                Hi
                  Hi
                    Hi
                      Hi
```

And my code was

```python
from subprocess import Popen, DEVNULL
from time import sleep
Popen(["ssh", "-R", "80:127.0.0.1:8080", "localhost.run"], stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=DEVNULL)
while True:
    print("Hi")
    sleep(1)
```

May be it is related to ssh but I'm not sure about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unix systems traditionally use a single linefeed character (ASCII 10, LF) as a line terminator. However, most terminals need a carriage return + linefeed sequence (CR+LF, 13+10) to move to the start of the next line. To handle this, the operating system's [line discipline](https://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) translates LF to CR+LF on output, and CR (from the terminal's RETURN key) to LF on input.

However, ssh opens a terminal connection to another system, and *expects that this translation will happen at the remote end! It therefore turns off this feature in the local line discipline!* This is why the end-of-lines that you are printing locally do not get translated.

You do not state what your goals are, so it is difficult to give a solution. A minimal "fix the symptoms" fix could be to give ssh the option `-T` to stop it from establising a terminal connection to the remote end (and just pass a "raw" data stream).

Comment: That worked magically. I just wanted to know how the Popen was affecting my print function wheres I've set the stdout and stderr to devnull and fix for it. Thanks!